# MacOS groff -mom unable to produce hyperlink

Tags: macos, mom, groff

I have been trying to output a pdf using groff mom. I am using the below:

```
groff -mom test.txt | pstopdf -i -o test.pdf
```

Everything is as expected, except it completely ignoring .PDF_WWW_LINK and I can't figure out why. I am on MacOS, and cannot use the compilation commands found here http://www.schaffter.ca/mom/pdf/mom-pdf.pdf.

I would like to avoid anything not included on a base install as I am making a script to be used across machines. Has anyone experienced this?

Thanks.

Comment: The `.PDF_WWW_LINK` macro will only work if you are using `groff -mom -Tpdf`. If it still doesn't work when you do that, then please provide a minimal reproducible example of the groff source you are using.